# Cron Expression being called multiple times

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

I'm trying to run a job every day at a specific time for testing purposes that should've been every day at 11:20:00 and for the real thing it should be every day at 23:59:59. For whatever reason the job just keeps getting triggered every 5 minutes and I'm not sure why. See the code here:

```
 static triggers = {
    cron name: 'reportTrigger', cronExpression: "0 20 11 ? * * *"
}

def execute(){
    //execute code that isn't relevant here
}
```

I'm on version 2.0.9 of the grails quartz plugin, I've tried newer versions but that causes non of the other jobs (that do actually have to run every 5 minutes) to no longer work.

Comment: cronExpression is fine. is it possible that you are using the same `cron name` between different jobs and one is overwriting another?

Comment: I don't think so no, I only use 2 cron jobs in this application. one is `reportTrigger` and the other is `licenseTrigger`

Answer (score 0):

quartz cron syntax is a little bit different from what you know from *nix. It has 6 parameters and the first one is seconds not minutes

Since this is grails 2 plugin it's difficult to find documentation anymore but in general the last parameter should be `?` as mentioned in https://github.com/9ci/grails-quartz2 bottom of the page. So your experssion would be: `0 20 11 * * ?` for `11:20:00`

Also, if you want to have different entry for PRODUCTION and testing you can add it like this:

```
static triggers = {
        if (Environment.current == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
            cron cronExpression: "0 0 * * * ?"
        } else {
            cron cronExpression: "0 */1 * * * ?"
        }
}
```